# Underlying hidden paragraph influencing positioning (cycle, masonry)

Tags: javascript, cycle, jquery-masonry, paragraph

What it boils down to is that the paragraph at the end of the slideshow is determening the overall minimum height of the item box and thus influencing the positioning of the overall website.

link to the website: http://degrafischeprofeet.be/website/ (just click any image to move the slideshow further, note that resize doesn't work in firefox or IE, also something i need to fix)

and an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NubXm.jpg

I have no idea where the problem could be exactly, so I'm just pasting the css of the text division

```
.projecttxt {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #000;
    color: #000;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-family:"georgia";
    padding: 5px 5px 0;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative !important;
}

<script>
$('#projectslide').cycle({ 
fx: 'fade', 
speed: 0, 
next: this, 
timeout: 0, 
fit: 1, 
slideResize: 1, 
reshape: 1, 
after: function() { $('#container').masonry('reload'); } });
</script>

  <div class="box col2">
<div id="projectslide" class="projectslide">
                        <img class="first" src="projects/5.jpg" alt="1">
                        <img src="projects/1.jpg" alt="2">
                        <img src="projects/7.jpg" alt="3">
                        <img src="projects/6.gif" alt="1">
                        <img src="projects/4.png" alt="1">
                        <div class="projecttxt">
                                                    <h1>Titeltje hier</h1>
                                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                                                    ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                                                    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
                                                    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently 
                                                    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                                    </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something that has `display:none` set can hardly affect _anything_, since per definition it behaves as if the element wasn't even part of the DOM at all. So highly unlikely that that's the _real_ cause of your problem. Go fix your HTML errors - http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://degrafischeprofeet.be/website/ - and see from there.

Comment: [Please don't only link to your site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), but post a minimal code example that reproduces the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i remove the paragraph from the slideshow the result is exectly like i want it to be.

Fixing the duplicate id's and removing the frames from youtube videos doesn't fix the problem though.